# Curl Login With csrf_token

Tags: php, php-curl

I am trying to login into a site using php curl but in page have multi csrf_token from form.
i was try with DOM and have 4 csrf_token value, this website for login https://www.useetv.com/login

an here is my code

```
$url = 'https://www.useetv.com/login';
$username = "email";
$password = "pass";
$cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt";
$agent  = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4098.0 Safari/537.36";

$POSTDATA = "email=".$username."&password=".$password."&csrf_token=value from hidden input";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_close ($ch);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POSTDATA);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
$content = curl_exec ($ch);
print_r($content);
curl_close ($ch);
```

how to get csrf_token from true form ?
please write with right code, thanks advance

Comment: the purpose of a csrf token is to block people from accessing the page from another page, so I don't think this is possible with php. Also a csrf token changes everytime so you can't get the csrf token with curl and place it in the form because the csrf token will change for the curl.

Comment: if with python ?